# Is it possible to conditionally apply different loaders, depending on different query params?

Tags: webpack, css-modules

I am trying to solve css-modules [global vs local css issue](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/pull/65) on webpack level.

The best solution I have right now is labeling files and run different loaders on them, which is tedious to use in real world project.

```
{
      test: /\.module.less$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!less-loader'
}
{
      test: /^((?!\.module).)*less$/,
      loader: 'style!css!less'
}
```

Let's say I have file styles.css

Somewhere in app code I want to write this:

```
var localCss = require('magicCSSLoader?local!./styles.css')
require('magicCSSLoader?global!./styles.css')
```

This is verbose, but

1. explicit, and can be configured later (localByDefault/globalByDefault)
2. better than renaming files all the time from git point of view
3. the same file can be processed differently

So my question is:

Is it possible to conditionally apply different loaders, depending on different query params?

```
loader: function(content, query) {
         if(query.local) {
           return webpackMagic(content, 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
         }
           return webpackMagic(content, 'style!css');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to generate module conditionally using [pitch](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#pitching-loader) loader:

```
var loaderUtils = require('loader-utils')

module.exports.pitch = function(remainingRequest) {
  var query = loaderUtils.parseQuery(this)
  if (query.local) {
    return `modules.exports = require("!!style!css?modules!${remainingRequest}")`;
  } else {
    return `modules.exports = require("!!style!css!${remainingRequest}")`;
  }
}
```

Comment: This really helped, but I am currently stucked on SSR and https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools, will update when I figure out this. Have no time currently.